# Getting specific event from calendar in android by _ID

Tags: android, kotlin, android-calendar

I have an event id sored in my android app. 
Now I want to get this specific event from calendar. Is that possible?

I have found various answers on how to get events from calendar, but none was working for my requirements.
[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#query) is documented how to get events from specific calendar. 
Constraints are set using `CalendarContract.Calendars` I believe I need to use `CalendarContract.Events._ID`
Here is what I've tried

```
private fun getCalendarEvents(ids: List<Long>): List<Pair<String, Long>> {
        val EVENT_PROJECTION: Array<String> = arrayOf(
            CalendarContract.Events._ID,
            CalendarContract.Events.TITLE
        )

        val PROJECTION_ID_INDEX: Int = 0
        val PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX: Int = 1


        val uri: Uri = CONTENT_URI
        val keys: String = ids.fold("") { acc, it -> "$acc, $it" }

        val selection: String = "${CalendarContract.Calendars._ID} IN ?"
        val selectionArgs: Array<String> = arrayOf("($keys)")
        val cur: Cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, EVENT_PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, null)!!

        val result: MutableList<Pair<String, Long>> =
            emptyList<Pair<String, Long>>().toMutableList()

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            val ID: Long = cur.getLong(PROJECTION_ID_INDEX)
            val TITLE: String = cur.getString(PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX)
            result += Pair(TITLE, ID)
        }
        return result
    }
```

It tries to load all events which have _ID in ids list and returns (Title, Id) pairs.

Is there any easy was how to accomplis this? There is an easy way for inserting, editing and deleting events [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-event) so I guess there must be something like that for fetching events as well.

Thank for help.